# Using GPUImage With a UIView

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm trying to integrate GPUImage into my app. Specifically, I want to apply the Sphere Refraction filter on my main view. Thing is, GPUImage works with UIImage, not with UIView. In order to create a UIImage representation of my view hierarchy, I'm using [CALayer renderInContext], which takes a long time to complete. The net result is that my animations look clunky.

Here's the code that's called in my CADisplayLink handler:

```
- (void)onDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink*)theDisplayLink {
  self.mainView.layer.opaque = YES;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.sphereView.bounds.size, self.sphereView.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
  [self.sphereView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage* mainViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  self.sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:mainViewImage smoothlyScaleOutput:NO];

  self.sphereRefractionFilter = [[GPUImageSphereRefractionFilter alloc] init];
  self.sphereRefractionFilter.radius = 0.5;
  self.sphereRefractionFilter.refractiveIndex = 0.25;
  [self.sphereRefractionFilter setInputRotation:kGPUImageRotate180 atIndex:0];
  [self.sphereRefractionFilter addTarget:self.mainView];

  [self.sourcePicture addTarget:self.sphereRefractionFilter];

  [self.sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

The view I'm trying to render using this code has a background image, and about 5-50 smaller images laid out on it, whose positions are modified in real-time. Imagine a sphere with multiple moving markers on it in various places.

Using this code, I'm able to render about 10 FPS. Question is: is there any way to do this faster?

Anyone?

Comment: Have you looked at the GPUImageUIElement input? It removes the need to do a round-trip through UIImage from the code above, and is slightly faster. Still, it's not quite clear what you want to do here. If you want to animate UI elements behind a filter, there really is no high-performance path to do that, because there's no way to feed composited UIKit elements directly into OpenGL ES currently.

Comment: I've edited the question - I hope it's clearer now. @BradLarson - appreciate you dropping by - I was kind of hoping you would :) I'll give GPUImageUIElement a shot. Thanks for the framework and for the help!

Comment: Looking at your code again, you really shouldn't be allocating a new filter every single time you want to process a new image or configuration of your UI elements. It's expensive to allocate a filter and set up its backing framebuffer, so just allocate the filter once and store it as an instance variable. If you set up a GPUImageUIElement once as well, keeping that as an instance variable, you can just update the UI element rendering every time something changes. That will be far more efficient than rebuilding everything every single frame.